# For Loop not working in Jinja/Flask

Tags: mongodb, flask, jinja2, pymongo

In jinja template my code is something like this, I m trying to get values from my MongoDB database

```
{% for a in output %}
        {{ a.product_name }}
{% else %}
        <p> No product found </p>
{% endfor %}
Some HTML CODE
{% for b in output %}
         {{ b.product_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is first loop is working fine, but second loop not at all working. But when I write the second loop before first loop, then second loop work but then not first loop ( it going inside else and printing "No Product Found").

I am not able to understand this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the `output` is an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator). Try to convert it to a `list` (or `dict`) inside a view function.

You can reproduce such behaviour by the next code:

```
output = (x for x in range(3))
# output = list(output)  # if uncomment this line, the problem will be fixed
for x in output:  # this loop will print values
    print(x)  

for x in output:  # this loop won't
    print(x)
```

**UPD:** Since the `output` is a mongodb cursor, you can rewind it by calling `output.rewind()` [directly](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#other-operators) in the template.

```
{% for a in output %}
    {{ a.product_name }}
{% else %}
    <p> No product found </p>
{% endfor %}

Some HTML CODE

{% set _stub = output.rewind() %}  {# use a stub to suppress undesired output #}

{% for b in output %}
     {{ b.product_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes I tried that to rewind in template, but that also print the Object Cursor on page, which is unwanted. But converting it into list worked fine.

Comment: @ArpitKanodia, I've update an example. Using `{% set _stub = output.rewind() }` fixes this issue with unwanted output to the template.

Comment: Thnx this worked, I never knew this property of set. Afterall I am new to Flask & Jinja. :P

Answer (score 4):

You want to iterate over the mongodb cursor twice. So after first iteration, you need to call the `rewind` method on the `output` (cursor) somewhere between the two loops.

```
output.rewind()
```

I am not sure if you would be able to do this in the Jinja template itself.

So the better option would be to convert the pymongo cursor object into a list itself, so you can iterate multiple times.

```
output_as_list = list(output)
```

Now you should be able to use `output_as_list` in your code the way you expected.

Comment: Yes I thought so that this was Cursor problem, and not able to iterate data again. But I was not able to how I rewind in jinja template. Thnxs this worked great.